# Проблема с работой библиотеки <iostream.h> и <conio.h>

Tags: c++, linux

Недавно перешел на ubuntu и возникла проблема с работой библиотек "iostream.h" и "conio.h". При попытке скомпилировать код, выскакивает ошибка такого типа "iostream.h: Нет такого файла или каталога". Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильно - `#include <iostream>`.

`<iostream.h>` - это какой-то старый вариант, не соответствующий стандарту. Я его видел только в древнем Borland C++.

`<conio.h>` - тоже нестандартный, но вдобавок не входит в стандартную библиотеку. На большинстве компиляторов для windows он есть, но на линуксе его нет. Ищите какую-нибудь билиотеку на замену.

Comment: Прошу прощения за такой глупый на мой взгляд вопрос) Во всем разобрался и дело решалось одной строчкой вида "g++ file.c", а не "gcc file.c". Сообщение об ошибке пропало моментально)) С библиотекой <conio.h>, разобрался еще проще, нашел альтернативу - #include <ncurses.h>

Comment: @V.Kvach, внутри ncurses.h есть инклюд stdio.h.

Comment: @isnullxbh Может conio.h? stdio.h ведь стандартный.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, stdio. Это и решило проблемы с ф-ями ввода\вывода :)